# Canon EOS 600D as Webcam

Tags: drivers, 18.04, webcam, canon

I am trying to figure out a way to get a video stream from a Canon EOS 600D to my system, basically using the camera as a webcam. While Canon offers software called [Canon EOS Utility](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/software/eos-utility.aspx) for Windows and Mac, it seems they do not offer anything for Linux. Just connecting the system with micro USB only enables to access the photos and videos stored on the SD card.

Is there any way to use the Canon EOS 600D as a webcam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.  The two paths to this that people have used are:

1. Use the included utility software which includes a live view window and run a software capture of what's in that window.  This unfortunately probably won't work at all on Linux.
2. Use the HDMI output of the camera and capture this with capture hardware.

I suspect that in both cases the live view video you'll get will be standard def and/or low quality and with limited ability to do any adjustments to things like frame rate, shutter speed/angle, etc.  On some Canon cameras you may find that the HDMI output has controls on the display including a focusing rectangle which can't be disabled even in the minimal display mode.

Answer (score 0):

`gphoto2` can capture movies from an EOS 600D and these can be forwarded to `ffmpeg` and consecutively to v4l2 to provide the videos as a standard webcam stream.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsuY4o2zLVQ for detailed instructions.

In summary:

- `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 max_buffers=2`
- `sudo apt install gphoto2 ffmpeg v4l2loopback-utils`
- `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1`

You may have to change the video codec (`rawvideo`), pixel format (`yuv420p`) and target video device (`/dev/video1`), but after this, the video stream from the camera should be available on `/dev/video1`.